# Autofac: how to inject properties with dynamic values?

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

By Autofac, it's easy to inject a static value to the `CurrentDate` property to instances of classes in a given assembly:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(asm).WithProperty("CurrentDate", new DateTime(2012, 1, 13));
```

However, how to inject dynamic values e.g. values returned by a `lamda () => { return DateTime.Now; }` to the `CurrentDate` property?

Comment: Could you provide more context for this?  Do you just need to override it in your own code, or also in code outside your control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you could use pretty standard property injection, like this:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(asm)
    .OnActivating(e => { e.Instance.CurrentDate = DateTime.Now; });
```

Note that you may need to cast `e.Instance` as it will probably be of type Object.

See [Lifetime Events in the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/LifetimeEvents) for more info.

On second thought, why not just put the initialization in the base class constructor?

```
public DateTime CurrentDate { get; private set; }
protected ApiController() { CurrentDate = DateTime.Now; }
```

The current date isn't really a dependency you need a DI container to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Register another service that provides your dynamic values (e.g. `IDateTimeService`) [I assume it's really something more complex than a DateTime that you want.]  The default lifetime for this new service will be [Instance per dependency](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/InstanceScope) but you could use "Per Matching Lifetime Scope".  Your Controllers will already be created per Http request.

Now simply add a dependency from your controllers on the `IDateTimeService` (in the constructor).  In the methods within that controller you can now get hold of the dynamic value you want from that service.

```
private static readonly IDateTimeService datetimeService;

public MyController (IDateTimeService datetimeService)
{
   this.datetimeService = datetimeService;
}


public void SomeMethod()
{
     var date = datetimeService.GetDate();
     ...
}
```

Comment: It'd generally be preferable to use `datetimeService.Date` as opposed to `datetimeService.GetDate()`.  Create a property named `Date` with a `get` accessor.  Also, this doesn't help if he's trying to change how code outside of his control deals with the property.

Comment: Sure, if it really is as simple as getting a date, use a getter, but I expect it's something a lot more complex in reality; that's not really the point of the example.

Comment: It's kind of vague.  I was going with the interpretation that he just wanted to override (literally, not polymorophically) the property under all circumstances, but it'd be nice if @Zach could provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom parameter like this:

```
public class DelegateParameter : Parameter
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly Func<object> _getValue;

    public DelegateParameter(string name, Func<object> getValue)
    {
        if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        if (getValue == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("getValue");
        _name = name;
        _getValue = getValue;
    }

    public override bool CanSupplyValue(ParameterInfo pi, IComponentContext context, out Func<object> valueProvider)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = GetProperty(pi);
        if (propertyInfo == null || propertyInfo.Name != _name)
        {
            valueProvider = null;
            return false;
        }
        valueProvider = _getValue;
        return true;
    }

    private static PropertyInfo GetProperty(ParameterInfo pi)
    {
        var methodInfo = pi.Member as MethodInfo;
        if (methodInfo != null && methodInfo.IsSpecialName && (methodInfo.Name.StartsWith("set_", StringComparison.Ordinal) && methodInfo.DeclaringType != null))
            return methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetProperty(methodInfo.Name.Substring(4));
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(asm).WithProperty(new DelegateParameter("CurrentDate", () => DateTime.Now));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to inject the lambda expression, rather than the result of the lambda expression, you have quite a few imperfect options.  Here are just a few; I'm sure that there are more.

### Autofac

The Autofac wiki on Google Project Hosting [documents four ways of injecting properties](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/PropertyInjection).  Three of them appear to use constant or default values--you mentioned one of these methods.

The final seems to give the developer a bit more control over properties.  It uses the [OnActivating](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/LifetimeEvents) event, during which you have a few options.  You could:

- Set the property and hope it sticks.
- If the property lacks an accessible setter, you could use reflection to set it, or its backing property (by default, m_PropertyName for a property named PropertyName, if I recall correctly).
- Wrap the instance in a proxy, as they put it: see **Polymorphism** below.

### Polymorphism

Let `ClassA` contain the property to be modified, `Prop1`.  Create a new class `ClassB` that extends `ClassA`.  If `Prop1` has a `virtual` modifier, you can override it.  Otherwise, use the `new` modifier to create a similar property in `ClassB` containing your dynamic code.

In the case of an override, you will need to instantiate `ClassB` in place of `ClassA`.  This will not work if the framework creates its own instances of `ClassA`, but as long as you create your own instances of `ClassB` and pass them to the framework, you should be good to go.

If you are using a new property, in addition to instantiating `ClassB`, you also have to ensure that whenever you access the new property, the object is cast to `ClassB` or a descendant type.  This generally will not work if another framework is designed to use `ClassA`, since it will always operate on type `ClassA`, not `ClassB`, regardless of your casting.

### Bytecode Manipulation

This is nasty stuff, but it will do exactly what you want.  C# generally compiles to an assembly/bytecode language called CIL.  Microsoft's variant is MSIL, but it's pretty much identical to generic CIL.

I've always used [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) for CLI/CLR (.NET, Mono) bytecode manipulation.  It seems to work flawlessly, and it's quite nice once you get the hang of it.  However, you have to know two things:

1. How to use CIL
2. How to use Mono.Cecil

The first one isn't that bad.  A few Wikipedia pages with detailed tables are all that you need, provided that you have sufficient experience with CLI.  If you think CLI stands for nothing other than "command line interface", then you might run into difficulty.

Mono.Cecil, on the other hand, lacked any form of proper documentation as of about a year ago (2012).  The learning curve was impossibly steep.  I had a miserable few days trying to figure it out.  It's amazing when it works, though.